# How to prevent form submit

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I am using KnockoutJS with SammyJS for one page application.

In the html I have form tag as follow

```
<form data-bind='submit: search'>
  <label>Find user:</label>
  <input data-bind='value: name' />
</form>
```

and in my viewmodel, declared two functions and sammy route url

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("");
    self.search = function () {
      alert(self.name);
    };

    Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#:id', function () {
           //do something....
        });           
    }).run();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

All code works good, until I type something in textbox then submit the form.
I expected no url browsing after alert window, but url is changed to something like this "http://localhost:8258/undefined?"
my original url is "http://localhost:8258"

I doubted sammy url routing, so removed sammy code from javascript code, then url does not change after alert window. 
Maybe I do not understand how sammy works.

How to prevent url change it this case?

Comment: have you tried returning `false` from your `self.search` function?

Comment: thanks Gene, I noticed that I did not set post route in Sammy.

Comment: Minor point... since `self.name` is a function, you should be calling `alert(self.name())`.

Answer (score 5):

Sammy binds itself to forms to enable you to register routes for them as well.

```
<form action="#1234" method="post">
```

JS:

```
Sammy(function() {
    this.post('#:id', function() {
        // do something...

        return false; // avoid form submission
    });

    // ...
}).run();
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem and I found a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14861466/1537441). Here is how you can make Sammy.js to leave the forms alone:

```
Sammy(function() {

    // Your routing.. 
    this.get('#:id', function () {
       //do something....
    }); 


    // Make Sammy.js leave the forms alone!
    this._checkFormSubmission = function(form) {
        return false;
    };

}).run();
```

Works like it should :)